# how can i convert backward slashes to forward slashes in perl

Tags: perl

i am taking one variable 
`$var2="\\hydfs00\PUBLIC1\DEV\pkumar\ITT_TEST_BUILD\CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated";`

and want to change it to

`$var2="//hydfs00/PUBLIC1/DEV/pkumar/ITT_TEST_BUILD/CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated";`

I'm using syntax `$var2 =~ s/\\/\//g;` for changing this. but the output is coming like  `/hydfs00PUBLIC1DEVpkumarITT_TEST_BUILDCS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated`

please help me out.

Comment: Turning on "use warnings" would have given you a big clue to what the problem is. That should always be your first step when tracking down a problem with Perl.

Comment: I've taken the Ant tag off - suggest you ask a separate question for that.  I'm not sure why you would want to do this sort of substitution - some sort of windows/unix portability issue perhaps?  Both Ant and Perl have mechansisms for dealing with directory paths in a portable way that are more robust than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"\\hydfs00\PUBLIC1\DEV\pkumar\ITT_TEST_BUILD\CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated"` is a mistake:

```
Unrecognized escape \P passed through at …
Unrecognized escape \D passed through at …
Unrecognized escape \p passed through at …
Unrecognized escape \I passed through at …
Unrecognized escape \C passed through at …
```

It evaluates to `\hydfs00PUBLIC1DEVpkumarITT_TEST_BUILDCS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated`.

You want to [single-quote the string](http://p3rl.org/op#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in order to restrict backslash-escaping to backslashes and single quotes only. `'\\hydfs00\PUBLIC1\DEV\pkumar\ITT_TEST_BUILD\CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated'` evaluates to `\hydfs00\PUBLIC1\DEV\pkumar\ITT_TEST_BUILD\CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated`.

Let's properly escape the backslashes at the beginning so we get two backslashes. `'\\\\hydfs00\PUBLIC1\DEV\pkumar\ITT_TEST_BUILD\CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated'` evaluates to `\\hydfs00\PUBLIC1\DEV\pkumar\ITT_TEST_BUILD\CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated`. This is the string you intended.

Now we can [operate](http://p3rl.org/op#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer) on the value.

```
my $var = '\\\\hydfs00\PUBLIC1\DEV\pkumar\ITT_TEST_BUILD\CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated';
$var =~ s{ \\ }{/}gx; # replace any single backslash with a single slash
# $var now has the value
# //hydfs00/PUBLIC1/DEV/pkumar/ITT_TEST_BUILD/CS2.1_PROD_TEST_40550_LG_LC_Java_sp36_obfuscated
```

This is all newbie stuff. Go [learn the language](http://learn.perl.org), [read a book or two](http://books.perl.org).