# Perl: Simple search and replace question

Tags: perl

I'm using ActiveState perl 5.12.4 on Windows 7.  I'm trying to execute a search and replace …

```
print "selected dir: $selected_dir basedir: $baseTestDir\n";
$selected_dir =~ s/$baseTestDir//g;
```

Where `$selected_dir = "\home\selenium\projects\myco\AutomatedTests\MyCliUSA\Critical Path\Live\G Sedan"` and `$baseTestDir = "\home\selenium\projects\myco\AutomatedTests\MyCliUSA"`.  However, after the search and replace statement, `$selected_dir` is unchanged.  How can I properly implement a search and replace here?

Comment: You haven't said how you are going to use the dir name. If you are going to use it in Perl without calling a Windows "shell", then you can use forward slashes instead of backwards slashes. eg. /home/selenium/projects...

Comment: Single backslashes in double-quoted string, as you have, mean something which you do not expect. Enable warnings! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788117/how-can-i-convert-backward-slashes-to-forward-slashes-in-perl for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't convert the text in `$baseTestDir` into a regex pattern. This can be using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
my $base_test_dir_pat = quotemeta($base_test_dir);
$selected_dir =~ s/^$base_test_dir_pat//;
```

It's also accessible via `\Q..\E` in double-quoted and similar string literals.

```
$selected_dir =~ s/^\Q$base_test_dir\E//;
```

A trailing `\E` can be omitted.

```
$selected_dir =~ s/^\Q$base_test_dir//;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the '\'s.

Do

> `$baseTestDir =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;`

before the replacement.

Comment: `quotemeta` or `/Q/.../` is a *much* cleaner and more general way to do this.

Answer (score -2):

I would write the following to replace selected_dir with baseTestDir:

```
    $selected_dir =~ s/$selected_dir/$baseTestDir/;
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing.  I want to remove $baseTestDir from $selected_dir.